# Strongly Cast a Reflection .GetValue() Object to a Generic DbSet

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, generics, reflection

I'm using EF 4.3.1 in VS 2010 (.Net 4.0) to load a number of reference tables from a database in order to bind them to controls in a WinForms app.

At form load, I'm pre-fetching the data so that it's stored locally, and I'm creating a dictionary of BindingSource objects that I can use to bind the local data to the controls.  The intent is to minimize the impact of the EF's self validation on a cold query in order to load forms faster and improve UI responsiveness.

I've written code to create and fetch the BindingSource object for a given DbSet collection as follows:

```
Private _dictBindings As New Dictionary(Of String, BindingSource)

Private Sub ValidateBinding(Of T As Class)(ByRef DbCollection As DbSet(Of T))
   Dim strClassName As String = DbCollection.[GetType]().GetGenericArguments(0).Name
   If Not _dictBindings.ContainsKey(strClassName) Then
      _dictBindings.Add(strClassName, New BindingSource With {.DataSource = DbCollection.Local.ToBindingList})
   End If
End Sub

Public Function GetBinding(Of T As Class)(ByRef DbCollection As DbSet(Of T)) As BindingSource
   ValidateBinding(Of T)(DbCollection)
   Return _dictBindings(DbCollection.[GetType]().GetGenericArguments(0).Name)
End Function
```

This code works, and I can call

```
ValidateBinding(Db.ProvinceStates)
```

or

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = GetBinding(Db.Cities)
```

However, I'd like to call ValidateBinding on all DbSet collections in the Model on startup, and I'd like to use reflection to iterate through the available collections in the context because we're currently loading 66 tables and could add more later.

I've written the following code:

```
For Each propSet As PropertyInfo In Db.GetType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public).Where(Function(P) P.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
    ValidateBinding(propSet.GetValue(Db, Nothing))
Next
```

...but it won't work as propSet.GetValue() returns an Object instead of DbSet(of T).  I also can't cast the object to a DbSet of the appropriate type, even though I know the type through reflection.

I don't have access to the C# Dynamic type, and I know it's a pain to mix generics with reflection, but is there a solution for which I can pass in a reflected DbSet to my functions?  Perhaps something using Method.Invoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've solved it, and the solution was with Method.Invoke.

First, I had converted my functions to Extension Methods.  Although this wasn't required, it does allow me to write:

```
db.ProvinceStates.ValidateBinding
```

and

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = db.Cities.GetBinding
```

Second, I used GetMethod, MakeGenericMethod, and Invoke to write the following:

```
Dim methodLoad = GetType(DbExtensions).GetMethod("Load", BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Public)

For Each propSet As PropertyInfo In Db.GetType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public).Where(Function(P) P.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
   Dim oSet As Object = propSet.GetValue(Db, Nothing)
   methodLoad.Invoke(Nothing, {oSet})

   Dim methodValidateBinding = GetType(DbSetExtender).GetMethod("ValidateBinding", BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Public).MakeGenericMethod(propSet.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments(0))
   If methodValidateBinding IsNot Nothing Then
      methodValidateBinding.Invoke(Nothing, {oSet})
   End If
Next
```

This kills two birds with one stone and loads the data for all 66 tables as well as creates their BindingSource objects to bind controls to.  (DbSetExtender is my own module that I put the extension methods in, whereas DbExtensions is part of the .Net framework.)